# How to place a variable inside of Directive HTML block and have it be accessed by Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that puts an HTML block onto the page. Inside that block I need there to be a variable that I can access and change, based on an `ng-click` function in my controller.

My directive:

```
.directive('sendModal', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="switchCurrency()">'+currency+'</div>'
    };
});
```

Function in Controller (using $parent because the modal exist on the parent level):

```
vm.$parent.switchCurrency = function() {
    console.log('clicked switchCurrency');
    if (currency === 'USD') {
        currency = 'BTC';
    } else {
        currency === 'USD';
    }
};
```

My error: **ReferenceError: currency is not defined**

How would you set a variable called `currency` inside of my directive HTML? And allow it to be accessible from the Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{currency}}` vs `'+currency+'`

This works, when it compiles it is able to turn into a variable

Comment: I don't understand. Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: why don't you share a scope in the directive such as `scope: { currency: '=' }` ? then in your controller change the currency and it will be reflected in the directive. It is cleaner than your solution.